# Excel Formula If cell contains specific text, otherwise math operation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

In cell G3, I would like the following:  If G2 equals Completed, then in G3 I would like it to say Completed, however if G2 is blank or has a date, I would like G3 to take the date in G2 and add 30 days.(G2+30)

Comment: So if G2 is blank, G3 should be 30?

Comment: If G2 is blank, G3 have the formula of G2+30.  Since G3 is a date column, it would default to 1/30/00

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(G2="Completed",G2,IF(OR(ISBLANK(G2),ISNUMBER(G2)),G2+30,""))
```

Or

```
=IF(G2="Completed",G2,IF(ISNUMBER(G2+0),G2+30,""))
```

Or

```
=IF(G2="Completed",G2,IFERROR(G2+30,""))
```

Or if the only options for input are a date, blank, or "Completed":

```
=IFERROR(G2+30,"Completed")
```

Comment: But one note on all of these approaches, they require that the blank is truly blank and not an empty string returned by a formula.